# Return reference and value inside std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to return somehow reference and value inside std::tuple.

Consider something like this:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <assert.h>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    int test = 99;
};

A a;

A& get_A() {return a;}

auto return_tuple_with_reference_and_value()
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(get_A(), 20);
}

int main()
{
    auto[reference_to_a, value] = return_tuple_with_reference_and_value();
    assert(reference_to_a.test == 99);
    assert(value == 20);
    reference_to_a.test = 1111;
    assert(a.test == 1111);
}
```

Can we make it work? Right now it has UB (dangling reference to '20').

Comment: No, C++ does not work this way. If a temporary gets used to construct a reference, that temporary is going to get destroyed, unless certain conditions are met that extend the lifetime of temporaries; but none of them apply in this case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think OP is looking for a function similar to `forward_as_tuple` that would return `tuple<A &, int>` in this case.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I'm looking for. I could simple replace reference with pointer and use make_tuple but it seems wired if we can't use reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) and pass a `reference_wrapper`

> For each `Ti` in `Types...`, the corresponding type `Vi` in `VTypes...` is `std::decay<Ti>::type` unless application of `std::decay` results in `std::reference_wrapper<X>` for some type `X`, in which case the deduced type is `X&`.

```
auto return_tuple_with_reference_and_value()
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::ref(get_A()), 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a standard function that does that, but writing one is not hard:

```
template <typename ...P>
auto foo(P &&... params)
{
    return std::tuple<P...>(std::forward<P>(params)...);
}
```